# How can i add permission to my own app that converted web(html,css,js) to android app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, leaflet, converters

I created a web browser app. In the app users can use leaflet routing machine and navigation to api locations. Also they can see their locations. This is how it works in web browser. Today i have converted to apk for android platform. I have opened it in my android phone so weather api, form submitter working good. Leaflet map working good too. But i can't check my location because the app doesn't request permission for location. I couldn't add it in android app settings. How can i fix this ?

```
var map2 = L.map('map2').setView([39,32], 13);
var osm2 = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map2);
var personicon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'icons/person-walking.png',
  iconSize: [40, 40],
});
fetch("https://www.nosyapi.com/apiv2/pharmacyLink?city=zonguldak&county=caycuma&apikey=zgD1WkxDpzSFpdSD5vNk8qjYxls8nhFwT4xeVqmn4EMrYcOKXCw1xyR0gU4r"
).then(response => {
  return response.json()
}
).then(responseJson => {
    console.log(responseJson)
var latitude0 = responseJson.data[0].latitude
var longitude0 = responseJson.data[0].longitude
var latitude1 = responseJson.data[1].latitude
var longitude1 = responseJson.data[1].longitude   
var latitude2 = responseJson.data[2].latitude
var longitude2 = responseJson.data[2].longitude   
var latitude3 = responseJson.data[3].latitude
var longitude3 = responseJson.data[3].longitude   
var latitude4 = responseJson.data[4].latitude
var longitude4 = responseJson.data[4].longitude 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
    function getPosition(position){
        console.log(position)
        var lat2 = position.coords.latitude
        var long2 = position.coords.longitude
        console.log('İşte Konumunuz, Enlem:' + lat2, 'Boylam:' + long2)
        var konummarker2 = L.marker([lat2, long2], {icon: personicon} ).addTo(map2)
        map2.flyTo([lat2, long2], 12);

        L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
              L.latLng(lat2, long2),
              L.latLng(latitude0, longitude0)
            ]
            
          }).addTo(map2); 
         
         
}});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this problem ip api. Getting location with api...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).